# Aren't Harutora and Natsume related?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

So in the end, Natsume and Harutora kissed. Isn't that weird? They are supposed to be cousins, right? Or was Natsume adopted? Which wouldn't explain her natural talent.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they're first cousins on their respective fathers' side.

---

Whether this is weird or not depends on your cultural background. In certain Hindu communities in north India, a relationship between fourth cousins would be deemed illicit, never mind first cousins. On the other hand, in certain parts of the Middle East, first-cousin marriages are quite prevalent, accounting for upwards of 30% of marriages in some places (e.g. [Jordan](http://www.economist.com/news/middle-east-and-africa/21693632-marriage-between-close-relatives-much-too-common-keeping-it-family) and [Saudi Arabia](http://english.alarabiya.net/en/life-style/art-and-culture/2015/04/04/Health-fears-question-Arab-tradition-of-cousin-marriages-.html)).

What about Japan?

My understanding is that first-cousin relationships in Japan are rare enough that they would be considered unusual ([this 1986 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3780039) suggests 1.6%; table 15 of [this whitepaper](http://www.ipss.go.jp/syoushika/bunken/data/pdf/14168401.pdf) suggests rates as high as 2.89% in some parts). However, they are not forbidden by law or by religious doctrine, and are generally not stigmatized to the same degree as in, say, the United States or most of Europe. Indeed, [Naoto KAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naoto_Kan) (prime minister of Japan 2010-2011) is married to his first cousin.

---

Getting back to the topic of anime, it's worth noting that same-generation incest is considerably overrepresented in anime and related "otaku" media relative to its occurrence in real life (for proof, observe that *Who is "Imouto"?* is a thing that exists). So, not only would a relationship between Harutora and Natsume not be that weird in real Japan, when you look at it from a "meta" point of view, it's even less weird that such a thing would happen in an anime.

Comment: Even 10000th cousin is deemed in India. Anyone with same last name cannot mary. No matter which number cousin. In some areas, you cannot mary even one with your mother surname, and in other places not even in same village, no matter what your last name is.

Answer (score 0):

According to volume 11 of the light novel, Natsumi was abandoned on the Wakasugi's door step after Harutora's mother died. So, yes, she is adopted.